# C++ / OpenCV - How can I reshape a cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` that has the dimensions of `40 rows X 32 columns`.

However, I need to reshape this `cv::Mat` so that it will have `100 rows X 32 columns`, willing the empty elements with `0`.

I have tried using the code:

```
cv::Mat mat1 = <from somewhere else>
mat1.reshape(mat1.cols, 100);
```

But it's failing with the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The total number of matrix elements is not divisible by the new number of rows) in reshape.
```

Has anyone had any experience in reshaping `cv::Mat` matrices? Likewise, I would really like to be able to take a `100 rows X 32 columns` matrix and go back to a `40 rows X 32 columns` matrix (and just truncate the extra rows); but I'm assuming if I solve one problem then I'll solve the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do this by using [`Mat::copyTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto):

```
Mat padded = Mat(100, 32, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
mat1.copyTo(padded(Rect(0, 0, mat1.cols, mat1.rows)));
```

On the other hand, if you want to get `40x32` back from the `100x32` `Mat`, it is also quite easy to do:

```
Rect roi(0, 0, 32, 40);
Mat mat1 = padded(roi);
```

---

Note that, [`Mat::reshape()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) is not suitable here as no extra elements are included into the new matrix and no elements are excluded.

Comment: This looks like a good approach. However, I am seeing a `No matching function for call to object of type 'cv::Mat'` on the `.copyTo` line. The error is pointing to the `padded`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can slice a `Mat` object using the [`Range`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#range) class in OpenCV. Ranges are exclusive which means that `Range(0, 4)` will refer to rows 1, 2 and 3 (it will not refer to row 4).

Here is an example that copies a 4x3 matrix into a 6x3 matrix. You can use this with any number of rows and columns:

```
Mat onesMat = Mat::ones(4, 3, CV_8UC1);
Mat zerosMat = Mat::zeros(6, 3, CV_8UC1);

cout<<"Before copying:"<<endl;
cout<<onesMat<<endl<<zerosMat<<endl;

// Copy onesMat to zerosMat. Destination rows [0,4), columns [0,3)
onesMat.copyTo(zerosMat(Range(0,4), Range(0,3)));


cout<<"After copying:"<<endl;
cout<<onesMat<<endl<<zerosMat<<endl;
```

And here is the output of the program:

```
Before copying:
[1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
After copying:
[1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
```